# Should I create new HttpClient for each new request?

Tags: android

I've got and rest api class that has several methods that perform http requests to my service. In constructor it create instance of HttpClient. Api instance is reused in different threads. Will it cause cross thread problems?

Currently i see two ways to make it thread safe:

1. Create new http client for each request.
2. Create separate instances of api class for each thread.

Comment: You can use synchronize method for remove cross thread problems.

Comment: Yep. I know. But from .NET experience it is not a good practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the overhead of creating a new HttpClient per call in a WebAPI client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000736/http-api-request-using-java-for-android/7001298#7001298) that may help. I basically use:

```
// Should be thread safe
public class HttpClientFactory {

            private static DefaultHttpClient client;

            public synchronized static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {
                    if (client != null)
                            return client;
                    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
                    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
                    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
                                    mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
                return client;

            }
    }
```

The question has the full posting.